# In Perl, how to access a variable defined in another package

Tags: perl, variables, scope, package

I have a generated perl script which I have no control over. It defines a package and a hash. I need to access the hash from another perl script that I do have full control over.

generated perl script:

```perl
package Animals;

my %pets = (
  'cat' => {
     'legs' => 4,
     'name' => 'Garfield',
     'speak' => 'Meowrrr!'
  },
  'bird' => {
     'legs' => 2,
     'name' => 'Tweety',
     'speak' => 'Pi pi pi!'
  },
  'dog' => {
     'legs' => 4,
     'name' => 'Pluto',
     'speak' => 'Wooof wooof!'
  }
)
```

The other perl script I have control over:

```perl
sub main {
  #some other code
  require Animals;
  #some other code
  #print for instance the what the bird's saying
  print $Animals::pets->{'bird'}->{'speak'};
}
```

I tried a variety of different syntaxes, but nothing worked for me. I'm completely new to perl so this is no big surprise really...

Comment: See also [In Perl, how can I access a scalar defined in another package?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4379257/2173773)

Comment: It is possible to access lexical variables of other scopes than the current, see e.g. [PadWalker](https://metacpan.org/pod/PadWalker), but that usually works if the other scope has called the current scope (so we can use [`caller`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html)) to trace back the stack. I am not sure how to do it for another package that is not on the call stack of the current sub.

Comment: @HåkonHægland `s/my pets/our pets/` before `do`  on the package file contents?

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, If there was a sub that used `%pets`, you could used PadWalker's `closed_over` to get to `%pets`. If there isn't, then I imagine that `%pets` is cleared when the module finishes executing (just like if it was a sub that finished executing).

Answer (score 3):

Since the assignment to the hash is the last thing in the file, you could use

```
my %pets = do('Animals.pm');
$pets{bird}{speak}
```

But the whole concept of "I have a generated file that's in an unusable format" makes no sense. When you change the output you generate, make sure to use something proper like JSON or YAML.

Answer (score 2):

The point of a lexical variable (i.e. one that is declared with `my`) is that it can only be seen inside its own lexical scope. Its lexical scope is the innermost code block that encloses the variable declaration or (in the absence of such a block) the file that contains the variable declaration.

Outside of the variable's lexical scope, there may be deep magic that you can use to access the variable, but that's really not recommended. A lexical scope is intended to be seen (at least as far as its variables are seen) as a black box. You cannot see the lexical variables inside it.

If you have a variable that needs to be seen across lexical scopes, then you need to make it a package variable. That is, you should declare it with `our` instead of `my`.

In your case, the smallest change that you can make to the generated module is to change `my` to `our`. It would also be useful if you could add the variable to the modules optional export list.

```
our @EXPORT_OK = qw[%pets];
our %pets = ( ... );
```

If you access a variable using a package name as you have here, then you are explicitly trying to access a package variable. Currently, this will fail for you as there is no package variable of that name.

If you just change `my` to `our`, then your code will work as it is currently written. If you make the additional `@EXPORT_OK` change, then you can simplify your code to:

```
use Animals qw[%pets];

print $pets->{'bird'}->{'speak'};
```

as `%pets` will have been imported into your package's symbol table.

Comment: I would add, the better option than either of these is to provide an interface to the variable via subroutines, which operate like package variables but would only allow as much access as you design.

Comment: @Grinnz: I agree completely. I only omitted that because the OP said they had no control over the module - so I went for the minimal solutions.